# What is this array function doing?

Tags: javascript, function

Could someone explain to me this (array[i + 1] and why would that determine the most frequent number in the array?

```js
function masFrecuente(array) {

  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i + 1] === array[i]) {
      let frecuente = array[i]
      return frecuente
    }
  }
}

let array = [3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3]
masFrecuente(array)
```

Gracias

Comment: I am not sure why people were so eager to close this as not being in English! The question is in English, and the only non-english words are in the code. Mas = More/Most; Frecuente = Frequent.

Comment: This does not work, just returns the the first number that appears twice in the array. Just play with the input array to see the issue. E.g. `array = [3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3]``

Answer (score 0):

#### It finds the first example of a number appearing twice, one-after-another, and returns that value

If there is no such case, it returns `undefined`, by default.

```js
function masFrecuente(array) {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i + 1] === array[i]) {
      return array[i]
    }
  }
}


console.log(masFrecuente([3, 5, 5, 3, 2, 3, 3])) // 5

console.log(masFrecuente([3, 5, 1, 3, 2, 3, 5])) // undefined

console.log(masFrecuente([3, 1, 2, 6, 7, 7, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3])) // 7
```

It is looking step-by-step through the array. At each step, it is looking at that element and the *next* element. As soon as it finds one such successive pair that are equal, it returns that value.

If it doesn't find such a pair, the function does not return anything. In Javascript, the calling function receives the value `undefined` in that case.